# What is a "short connection" and what is the tag with name for, and is it being used properly?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

I've just noticed we have four questions tagged as [short-connection](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-connection) but it has no tag wiki, no tag wiki excerpt, and it's intended use is not obvious to me:

- [Is 1h layover at PHL enough to connect to the next flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52342)
- [Separate flights on same itinerary](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51565)
- [Minimum time to transfer between Incheon and Gimpo airports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50868)
- [1 hour connection in Warsaw Chopin Airport - strategy for not missing the flight](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50082)

Is it some kind of "connection", which I think we don't have a tag for though I can't remember why, perhaps because we use the word "transfer" for that meaning?

Or is it something like a short layover, which in turn we already established a couple of years ago is a kind of short stopover?

Or is it something else? Is it a set term with a set meaning in air travel?

So are those four questions using the tag correctly? Or could it be that the OP's started looking for a tag "connection" and just picked this tag that the system suggested as a partial match?

(This struck me as being more purely a meta question than a couple of other questions I recently asked on the main page that seemed to be about travel terminology generally. I'm assuming this one is more about how we name tags? Tell me if I assume wrong.)

Comment: OK let's see if anyone else wanders into the fray with logic or venom ...

Comment: If you book a flight with a short connection, that's just above the legal MCT, you may well find yourself with non-standard needs/requirements to ensure you get to the next plane on time. I think it's a pretty well known and understood term within airline travel. It can also exist with trains too, again with additional requirements to get through/around/across/to in a quick way

Comment: @Gagravarr: I'm so ignorant that I don't know what MCT is either )-:

Comment: MCT = Minimum Connection Time. Tickets with a connection time of less than that aren't valid, and either can't be booked, or if the schedule changes to less than the MCT, need to be rebooked. Varies by airline and airport and terminal and origin and destination!

Comment: Also, some people call it a "short connection", some people call it a "tight connection". Most airlines call it "short connection", eg on extra baggage labels, but often call the people on it "express connection" (or similar) on boards / special queue jump vouchers etc

Comment: @Gagravarr: Would you care to write the tag wiki and excerpt since you are our expert on this topic? (-: Also please check the questions it's used on so far and see if it needs to be removed from any of them.

Comment: @hippietrail I've taken a stab, does it look OK to you?

Comment: @Gagravarr: You probably should mention what MCT is. I managed to forget already (-:

Comment: @hippietrail It's in paragraph #2, along with a definition, is that enough?

Comment: I put it also in the excerpt since many more people see that than the full wiki. If you post that you've done it as an answer to this meta question I can accept it by the way (-: